# How to hide class="hero-image" from search query page or "/search?q="?

Tags: search, full-text-search

In my "/search?q=" page, my hero-image appears. How can I stop it from appearing in search page? I have applied `.hero-image {display=none;}` in other web pages but I do not know how to do that for the search page.
Thank you.

I have tried `.hero-image .search-query {display=none;}` but nothing happened.